# Mysql 8 tables size

Tags: mysql, linux, mysql-8.0, centos

We have a problem with an unreasonably large table size on the server, for example:
Yesterday, a table with partitions was created, data began to be written to a specific partition.

```
mysql> show table status like 'in_followers_bots_p'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Name: in_followers_bots_p
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Dynamic
           Rows: 38517
 Avg_row_length: 73
    Data_length: 2818048
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 1589248
      Data_free: 4194304
 Auto_increment: NULL
    Create_time: 2021-05-04 14:58:32
    Update_time: 2021-05-04 14:59:45
     Check_time: NULL
      Collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
       Checksum: NULL
 Create_options: partitioned
        Comment:
```

But at the same time, the size of this table(partition) on disk 3.7G
`-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  3.7G May  5 12:29 in_followers_bots_p#p#p05.ibd`

mysql  Ver 8.0.20
Centos 8

This problem is observed with many tables, please tell me the reason for this problem and if there are solutions.
I will be happy to provide all the necessary information.

UPD

````
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE in_followers_bots_p\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: in_followers_bots_p
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `in_followers_bots_p` (
  `owner_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `bot_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `month_id` tinyint NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bot_id`,`owner_id`,`month_id`),
  KEY `in_followers_bots_owner_id_index` (`owner_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (`month_id`)
(PARTITION p01 VALUES LESS THAN (2) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p02 VALUES LESS THAN (3) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p03 VALUES LESS THAN (4) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p04 VALUES LESS THAN (5) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p05 VALUES LESS THAN (6) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p06 VALUES LESS THAN (7) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p07 VALUES LESS THAN (8) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p08 VALUES LESS THAN (9) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p09 VALUES LESS THAN (10) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p10 VALUES LESS THAN (11) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p11 VALUES LESS THAN (12) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p12 VALUES LESS THAN (13) ENGINE = InnoDB) */```
````

Comment: This can be for a number of reasons. Seeing the `CREATE` statement that defines the table might shed some light on the reason. Be sure to include the index definitions as well, as they can consume more storage space than the source data.

Comment: Hi, What was the preivous size ? How much it is increased ? What was the last character set you were using ? This can be possible because you might have changed to UTF8MB4 which occupies more space.

Comment: @matigo can you tell me how can ```CREATE``` statement help us find the problem?

Comment: You can retrieve the `CREATE TABLE` statement like this: `SHOW CREATE TABLE in_followers_bots_p;`

Comment: @JYOTIRAJAI preivous size is null, because table was create yesterday, we always use the charsets UTF8MB4. Data is being actively written in this table, but now in ```show table status``` I watch that ```Data_length: 202506240``` ```Index_length: 109821952``` ```Data_free: 4194304``` and in disk utilized  ```-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  4.0G May  5 16:26 in_followers_bots_p#p#p05.ibd ```

Comment: @matigo okey, added this information to the post!

Comment: what ROW_FORMAT do you use ?

Comment: @JYOTIRAJAI ```ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic ``` for all problem tables.

Comment: You won't have more than 126 months?

Comment: You should end with a partition `LESS THAN MAXVALUE`.  Even if you never use it, it could protect you from losing data in certain error cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by transferring data to a partition table with the parameter `ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED`.